# Setters y getters de array // Mostrar ultimos 3 C++

Tags: c++, poo

Me piden en un ejercicio, con POO hacer una clase banco que tiene un atributo *historial*, el cual debe ser un arreglo de 200, que serian pagos.

1. Quisiera llenar el arreglo con un `for` del 1 al 200, pero no se como utilizar (hablando de sintaxis) *setters* y *getters* con arreglos.
2. Como método me piden mostrar los 3 últimos elementos del arreglo pero no se me ocurre como implementar la función, si esta funciona bien debería mostrar: 197,198,199

Adjunto mi codigo, el cual se que esta mal, ayúdenme a corregirlo y si se puede alguna breve explicación me ayudaría mucho. Gracias.

###### `Banco.h`

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Banco{
private:
    string nombre;
    long nCuenta;
    float historial [200];

public:
    Banco ()=default;

    void setNombre(string);
    void setnCuenta(long);
    void setHistorial (float []);

    string getNombre ();
    long getnCuenta();
    float getHistorial ();

    void mostrar_3(); //no supe implementarla :c
};
```

###### `Banco.cpp`

```
#include "Banco.h"

void Banco::setHistorial (float _historial [200])
{

historial[200]=_historial[200];
for (int i=0;i<200;i++){
    historial[i]=i;
    cin>>historial[i];
}
}

float Banco::getHistorial ()
{
    return historial [200] ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar creo que vale la pena ahondar en lo que son los *getters* y *setters*: Son funciones que permiten escribir (*set*) o leer (*get*) datos de un objeto usando los principios del [encapsulamiento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulamiento_(inform%C3%A1tica)).

Conceptualmente, leer datos no modifica el objeto leído, así que todos tus *getters* deberían ser constantes y para evitar copias innecesarias de datos, deberían devolver referencias constantes al dato leído<sup>1</sup>:

```
class Banco{
private:
    string nombre;
    long nCuenta;
    float historial [200];

public:
    Banco ()=default;

    void setNombre(string);
    void setnCuenta(long);
    void setHistorial (float []);

    const string &getNombre() const;
    long getnCuenta() const;
    float getHistorial() const;

    void mostrar_3(); //no supe implementarla :c
};
```

Una vez dicho esto, observa tu *getter* del historial:

```
float getHistorial() const;
```

¿No te parece raro que si el historial son doscientos movimientos (`float[200]`) sólo devuelvas un movimiento (`float`)? Tal vez lo que querías era devolver el historial al completo:

```
class Banco{
private:
    using historial_t = float[200];

    string nombre;
    long nCuenta;
    historial_t historial;

public:

    ...

    const historial_t &getHistorial() const;

    ...
};
```

Con ese *getter* puedes mostrar los tres últimos movimientos así:

```
Banco b;

auto historial = b.getHistorial();

std::cout << historial[197] << ' ' << historial[198] << ' ' << historial[199];
```

Y si quieres un *getter* para los últimos X movimientos, puedes probar algo así:

```
template <std::size_t movimientos>
std::array<float, movimientos> getUltimos() const
{
    std::array<float, movimientos> result;
    auto ultimo = std::rbegin(historial);
    auto x = ultimo + movimientos;
    std::copy(ultimo, x, result.begin());

    return result;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZHPjoIwEIfP7VPMZhOF6BrcZC@AHDztC@zJmE3ByjaBlvSP0TU8OzsUFD3tBSj9@v1mOkXTvBUVk2XXvQpZVO7AIRXKWM1ZndHpH9OaXTJKETYGtvRKiTNClvAjjFVasOrbwgaOlWJ29x5F@4SSx63797VNaOPyShQxJdsgpARV5Kg0BEJaECiJEny9bAA1CSwWAhkyyXZij4xAf0spKZQ09qmIWcnt520dhOCJIUVz67Sc6NFhed1UzGKXxh7i2Ihfjp5anUQtuLTKZJT4HX8Jqe9x@bQPmPlVWVEr85z4zzHNjasslkGYswqcV2B3/pjOeSlkcK82vHNnREZ28ShMbomFai7BQCzhvBxzVoMwRNF0GfcSWoqTof0MatZT/Yi3kPesn85w0z5/doIY8tXUdLr@yNA7xTsLaQqn/jGHee8Y46KEtl23jiL6Bw)</kbd>.

---

###### <sup>1</sup>Para tipos básicos no es necesario devolver una referencia constante pues una copia es igual de eficiente que una referencia de sólo lectura.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui un ejemplo sobre cómo llenar y mostrar un array como atributo de una clase. La gestion de dicho array (el de llenar y mostrar) es sopoprtado por la interaccion entre dos variables, uno que contiene el tamaño y otro que contiene la cantidad de elementos que actualmente tiene el array, para este ejemplo el tamaño del array se define en la constante `static const int CAPACIDAD` y para llevar el conteo de elementos se definie la variable `int numElementos_` entonces para responder a la pregunta como hacer el metodo setArray en realidad se hace elemento por elemento y es este mismo metodo `void agregar(float elemento)` el encargado de verificar si hay espacio o no en el array para agregar un nuevo elemento

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

/*======== Declaracion Contenedor ========*/

class Contenedor{
private:
    static const int CAPACIDAD = 5;
    int numElementos_;
    float array_[CAPACIDAD];
public:
    Contenedor();
    void agregar(float elemento);
    float getElemento(int indice) const;
    int tamanio() const;
    void ultimosTres() const;
};

/*======== Funcion principal ========*/

int main() {
    Contenedor contenedor;

    contenedor.agregar(1);
    contenedor.agregar(2);
    contenedor.agregar(3);
    contenedor.agregar(4);
    contenedor.agregar(5);

    cout<<"\tUltimos tres elementos\n\n";
    contenedor.ultimosTres();

    cout<<"\n\tTodos los elementos\n\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < contenedor.tamanio(); i++){
        cout<<contenedor.getElemento(i)<<"\n";
    }

    return 0;
}

/*======== Definicion Contenedor ========*/

Contenedor::Contenedor() : numElementos_(0){}

void Contenedor::agregar(float elemento){
    if(numElementos_ < CAPACIDAD){
        // mientras numero de elementos sea menor a la capacidad entonces se agrega el elemento
        array_[numElementos_] = elemento;
        numElementos_++; //una vez agregado incrementar en 1
    }
}

float Contenedor::getElemento(int indice) const{
    return array_[indice];
}

int Contenedor::tamanio() const{
    return numElementos_;
}

void Contenedor::ultimosTres() const{
    for(int i = tamanio() - 3; i < tamanio(); i++){
        cout<<getElemento(i)<<"\n";
    }
}
```